# iPhone switch from full screen UINavigationView to UITabView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Newbie question but I can't find the answer.

On first run my app is navigation view to walk the user through setup.
When this is done and I am storing the data.

I start this in my delegation by doing : 
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

In my delegation at startup if the data is set I do the following for a tabview.
[self.window addSubview:tabRootController.view];

My mainwindow.xib has both views.

All is good (don't know if what I have done is the best way , but it is working).

Anyway my problem is when I get to the end of navigation view and they hit the save , how do I get rid of the navigation view and bring up the tab view ?

I can't see a way I can get my delegate to add the subview, and the subview does not exist in the screen I am in - so I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to have:

- The MainWindow as a TabBar application.
- When loading the app and data is required, use a `presentModalViewController:animated:` for the setup with its NavigationController.

This has the advantage that both are view controller are completely independent from each other, and if you later need to show the setup again, you can present the modal view controller from anywhere in your app with a single call.